# How to pass variables to request callback without using a forloop?

Tags: node.js

For example if I like to do:

```
var request = require('request');

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
  console.log(body);
}

var cookie = {
  '74358942795': 'abd7fce573c2-18c2c0de-037f-4aef-9235',
  '58942743795': 'e3101e9a0e28-b596998e-e879-4003-a724'
}

function options(num) {
  return {
    url: 'http://.../.../',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      ...
      'Cookie': cookie[num]
    },
    body: '...=' + Date.now()
  };
}

(function(num){
  request(options(num), callback);
})('74358942795');
```

Here within the callback it will return `num undefined` and throw an error.

Comment: You could use currying https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe or a lambda instead of callback directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor's answer is almost right. It should be:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  var that = this;
  if (that.num) {
    console.log(that.num);
  }
  console.log(body);
}

(function(num){
  request(options(num), callback.bind({num}));
})('74358942795');
```

Comment: no, Igor's answer is right - no "almost", and your code is wrong - there will be parameter mismatch

Answer (score 1):

`num` isn't available to the `callback` scope. Simplest solution I see would be to replace that last block with:

```
(function(num){
  request(options(num), function (error, response, body){
    if (num) {
      console.log(num);
    }
    console.log(body);
  });
})('74358942795');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get how "forloop" is related to the code in question. Use bind:

```
function callback(num, error, response, body) {
  if (num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
  console.log(body);
}

(function(num){
  request(options(num), callback.bind(null, num));
})('74358942795');
```

```js
function callback(num, error, response, body) {
  if (num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}

(function(num) {
  setTimeout(callback.bind(null, num), 1000);
})('74358942795');
```

Comment: You bet. *(7 more to go...)*

Comment: Still return `num undefined`.

Comment: Ops, I've noticed I forgot to put `num` in the argument list of the callback function.